# Hyperledger fabric :Failed to join all peers to channel. cause:TypeError: client.getEventHubsForOrg is not a function

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PrqT.png)Hi Guys I am facing following error "Failed to join all peers to channel. cause:TypeError: client.getEventHubsForOrg is not a function" while running node SDK setup any could help me I am running Balance transfer example

[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTmPu.png)

Comment: can you please add the sample code as well.

Answer (score 3):

This should work.
In app/joinChannel.js
Replace `let event_hubs = client.getEventHubsForOrg(org_name);`
with  `let event_hubs = channel.getChannelEventHubsForOrg(org_name);`